# Val Loss starts close to zero and stays - Train loss normal

Tags: python, validation, tensorflow, keras, loss-function

I am trying to optimize my LSTM regression based forecasting model. Therefore i put a loop in my code to find the best learning rate. But i think something is wrong. The validation loss it starts close to zero and remains there (compare picture).  [Training- and Val-Loss](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ylexN.png)

Comment: This doesn't need to be an error. Can you provide some code where you show how you calculate the losses? How does the plot look like if you devide the train/val-losses by the number of train/val-samples?

Comment: I simply used the MSE-Score
`model.compile(optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(lr=0.001), loss='mean_squared_error')`

`history = model.fit(x=X_Training, y=y_Training, 
                                epochs=1000,
                                batch_size=BATCH_SIZE,
                                validation_data=[X_Validierung, y_Validierung],
                                shuffle=False,
                                callbacks=[earlyStopping, mcp_save],
                                verbose=0)`

Comment: Looks fine so far. What ratio is your train/validation-split? How many instances do you have overall?

Comment: How can i devide the train/val-losses by the number of train/val-samples.
I am not sure how to do that.

Totaly i have 533 samples.
300 for training (roughly 55%)
130 for validation (roughly 25%)
103 for test (roughly 20%)

Comment: `model.fit()` returns a "history-object" where train- and val-losses of the epochs are saved. Have a look at this https://machinelearningmastery.com/display-deep-learning-model-training-history-in-keras/.

Answer (score 0):

You have very little data for the purpose of deep learning.

According to the graph, it is very likely that you are overfitting to the validation set. There are other cases in which the validation loss can be smaller than the training loss, considering the cases in which the dropout is not enabled when testing and/or the validation is really easy.

My suggestion is to increase your dataset considerably, at least 20000 samples in total split in the following fashion (16000 - 2000 - 2000). LSTMs require a lot of data to train upon.